# Responsive shuffling of divs

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Ideally, I want to display group 1 and 2 side by side, but should the browser window shrink, I want group 2 to move below group 1.

I'm having all sorts of issues with text inside the div containing text/image moving below the image and just general bizarre behaviour.

What is the best way to go about containing all of these things in this manner?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. You are more likely to get helped!

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to achieve, but I don't quite get the "bizzare behavior". Could you show us how you achieve the vertical stacking so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way will be to create a parent `div` with `display:flex` and using `flex-direction:row` for bigger screens and then create a breakpoint for smaller screen and use `flex-direction:column` for that.

Here is an example -

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1"></div>
  <div class="child-2"></div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS -

```
.parent {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

@media all and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 600px) {
  .parent {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
/*Feel Free to change the screen sizes here and add browser prefixes*/
```

This is just a basic example. If you're using the newly released **Bootstrap 4** beta, then it ease your work to a great extent. You don't have to worry about compatibility and browser prefixes.

You can learn more about `CSS Flex` here - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/